Will increasing Furnace and AC tonnage be ineffective without increasing return and supply ducts?
I currently have a 2.5 ton system which is struggling to cool in the summer.  The interior ducts have been replaced recently, and 3 contractors all suggest an increase to 3 tons.  I am unclear if the supply or return ducts are 12" or 14", but one contractor stated 12" is inadequate. Google says even bigger ducts are required.  The cost to increase these ducts is about $2,000. Am I wasting my money with a 3 ton unit if I don't increase the duct size? The furnace and blower are in the garage.  The supply side duct only has about an 8 foot run into the house, where airflow is eventually constrained by the smaller interior ducts. With this constraint, why is it important to increase the garage duct for this 8 foot run? The return duct in the garage is longer and is fed by an open space in the hallway (1980 built place). Do I need a larger size for both ducts?

bigger ducts run quieter for the same flow rate. duct has to deliver the mass flow rate to all outlets at the same time - so use that to work out the flow rates required. If you don't understand then get a good contractor to check the sizing required.

How is the house insulated and sealed.  1980 build might be 2x4 wall studs, so maybe R-12 to R-15.  Ceiling insulation is usually the easiest to increase.  Better insulation might be a better cost expense than a bigger system.  The size/square footage is an important factor also.
